# Java web installer - How'd they do that?

Tags: java, installation, applet

Does anyone know how Citrix gets this installer to push an EXE straight out from a web page, and install it into the start menu as if it were a regular downloaded installer?

https://support.gotoassist.com/download/repDownload

I'm stumped!

Is this Java Web Start in action?  If so how do they get it started without downloading a JNLP?  (or do I have *something* installed on my computer previously that I'm not aware of that allows this?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: GoToMeeting JNLP prompt]

This is a Java Applet security prompt.  Since the Applet is a signed Applet, it is granted permissions to interact with things on your computer, such as downloading and launching an installer.